# Publish Italian land registry WMS service in qgis2web

Tags: openlayers, wms

I try to publish this WMS in qgis2web but it does not appear on the qgis2web web map.
I usually use the SR EPSG 3004 but I can change if this is the problem.

https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php

Supported EPSGs are 6707, 4258, 3044, 3045, 3046, 25832, 25833, 25834.

I correctly display the level in qgis
Warning: png and jpg maps are activated when you go below the 1:5000 scale in the Italian territory (i zoom in Fano city).

I am interested to including these separate map layers:

mappe, fabbricati, particelle.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the axis order of EPSG:3044 is a problem?  Try 25832 instead.  Also for mappe to work in OpenLayers it needs LAYERS': 'CP.CadastralZoning', not mappe.

Comment: I think you are in the wrong site. This site is for programming. We have other sister sites (see links on top right icon), one of then discusses about GIS.

Comment: Yes @Mike, it was the use of the wrong epsg. I don't understand why, but if I apply SR 25832 to the qgis project and export with qgis2web everything works. Obviously you have to go below a certain scale for the levels to be seen. PS: I inserted the wms layers in the legend after setting the project's SR, in doing so they also took the 25832.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the use of the wrong epsg. I don't understand why, but if I apply SR 25832 to the qgis project and export with qgis2web everything works. Obviously you have to go below a certain scale for the levels to be seen. PS: I inserted the wms layers in the legend after setting the project's SR, in doing so they also took the 25832.

Comment: EPSG:3044 and EPSG:25832 use the same coordinates except one is [y, x] and the other is [x, y].  I think qgis2web does not correctly handle the [y, x] order for WMS.